# useEffect pair causing infinite loop if typing too fast in sub-form

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, infinite-loop

I've got a form updating a state's array elements independently, but the way it's made causes an infinite loop when "typing too fast" in the form.

The `section` state is meant to be a copy of the `data.sections` item. Every section can have multiple `profiles` in it, and we can modify every `profile` data within a form.

**Typing too fast in the `profile` form causes the `section` useEffect to loop infinitely.**

This was noted through console.logs in the first two useEffect hooks - no excessive logs were thrown from the `ProfileForm` component, so this must be tied to the `section` component

The `sections` component:

```js
const {data, setData} = props

const [sections, setSections] = React.useState<any[]>(data.sections)

// how sections are made
// sections = [
//     {
//         name: "",
//         profiles: [
//             { name: "" }
//         ]
//     }
// ]

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (sections && (sections !== data.sections)) {
            setData({...data, sections: sections})
        }
    }, [sections])

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (data.sections && (data.sections !== sections)) {
            setSections(data.sections)
        }
    }, [props])

// ...

{
    sections && sections.map((section: any, sectionIndex: number) => {
        return (
           <>
               {section.name}

               {
                 section.profiles && section.profiles.map((profile: any, profileIndex: number) => (
                      <ProfileForm
                         key={profileIndex}
                         {...{sections, setSections, sectionIndex, profileIndex, profile, t}}
                       />
                 ))
               }

           </>
       )
   })
}
```

The `person` component:

```js
const {sectionIndex, profileIndex} = props

const [profile, setProfile] = React.useState(props.profile)

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (profile && (profile !== props.profile)) {
            handleProfileChange(sectionIndex, profileIndex)
        }
    }, [profile])

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (props.profile && (props.profile !== profile)) {
            setProfile(props.profile)
        }
    }, [props])

    const handleProfileChange = (sectionIndex: number, profileIndex: number) => {
        let _profiles= sections[sectionIndex].profiles
        _profiles.splice(profileIndex, 1, profile)

        let _sections = [...sections]
        _sections.splice(si, 1, { name: _sections[sectionIndex].name, profiles: _profiles })
        setSections([..._sections])
    }

   return (
      <input onChange={(e: any) => setProfile({...profile, name: e.target.value})} value={profile.name} />
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see a chain of events that will lead to an infinite loop due to the way you've structured your React logic;

When the input changes in the Person component it calls setProfile(), the component re-renders and the first useEffect is then triggered. This in turn calls the handleProfileChange(), which itself then calls setSections() within the Sections component (where the issue is).

The Sections component then re-renders and its first useEffect is called because setSections() was called from the Person component and 'sections' has changed (its in your first useEffects dependency array). This useEffect then calls setData().

Now here is where the infinite loop starts, because you are passing down setData() and data from a parent component via the props into the Sections component, which in itself is fine, but you have that second useEffect that has 'props' in its dependency array. The first useEffect just called setData(), so 'data' has just changed and therefore now the second useEffect is triggered. The second useEffect then calls setSections(), which triggers the first useEffect again that calls setData(), and there is the cycle.